# Text Gradient in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Can't figure out how to add a ***gradient*** to a text with an ***inner shadow*** with a modifier in Jetpack Compose.
To have something like this? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So far jetpack compose doesn't provide text gradient and inner shadow out of the box.
Hence need to paint it by yourself:

[image: result image]

```
@Composable
fun drawGradientText(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val paint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint()

    val gradientShader: Shader = LinearGradientShader(
        from = Offset(0f, 0f),
        to = Offset(0f, 400f),
        listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Cyan)
    )

    Canvas(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        paint.apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            textSize = 400f
            typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
            style = android.graphics.Paint.Style.FILL
            color = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#cdcdcd")
            xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER)
            maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(30f, Blur.NORMAL)
        }
        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            canvas.save()
            canvas.nativeCanvas.translate(2f, 5f)
            canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(name, 0f, 400f, paint)
            canvas.restore()
            paint.shader = gradientShader
            paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            paint.maskFilter = null
            canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(name, 0f, 400f, paint)
            canvas.nativeCanvas.translate(2f, 5f)
            paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER)
            paint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(30f, Blur.NORMAL)
            canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(name, 0f, 400f, paint)
        }
        paint.reset()
    }
}
```

You can adjust PorterDuff modes and offsets to meet your requirements.

Comment: Could you also help with this question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996525/x-and-y-offset-blur-and-opacity-of-shadow-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 18):

In Jetpack Compose [1.2.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-beta01) text gradients [were added](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2063048/).

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BrushDemo() {
    Text(
        "Brush is awesome\nBrush is awesome\nBrush is awesome",
        style = TextStyle(
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = RainbowColors,
                tileMode = TileMode.Mirror
            ),
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )
    )
}
```

More examples [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/changes/48/2063048/17/compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/text/BrushDemo.kt#83).

Answer (score 16):

Just ran into the same use case, but just for a simple gradient on text. Posting it here in case it helps someone.

What worked for me was drawing the content and then the gradient via `Modifier.graphicsLayer` (extrapolated from [this](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1637126215065100?thread_ts=1637122989.063200&cid=CJLTWPH7S) answer on Slack):

```
Text(
   text = "$ 20",
   /** size/font style, etc. **/
   modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
     .drawWithCache {
        val brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(StartColor, EndColor))
        onDrawWithContent {
            drawContent()
            drawRect(brush, blendMode = BlendMode.SrcAtop)
        }
     }
)
```

I ended up making it a `Modifier` for reuse:

```
fun Modifier.textBrush(brush: Brush) = this
   .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
   .drawWithCache {
      onDrawWithContent {
         drawContent()
         drawRect(brush, blendMode = BlendMode.SrcAtop)
      }
   }
```

Example Result:

[image: text with gradient]

Comment: It looks a lot simpler when you do it this way。
Alpha = 0.99F is critical