# X and Y offset, blur, opacity and colour of shadow in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack, shadow, android-jetpack-compose

Since Jetpack Compose has [this limitation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122?pli=1) I'm looking for workaround solution for this problem?

Maybe Canvas could do the trick? I really appreciate if someone can provide code snippets of how to render shadow in Jetpack Compose for `Card`, `Box`, `Column`, `Row` etc utilising additional parameters like X and Y offset, blur and opacity with custom implementation (Canvas or something else)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I managed to find solution thanks to this [code snippets](https://gist.github.com/cedrickring/0497965b0658d6727aaec531f59e8c5c)

```
@RequiresApi(Q)
fun Modifier.advancedShadow(
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    alpha: Float = 1f,
    cornersRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    shadowBlurRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetY: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetX: Dp = 0.dp
) = drawBehind {

    val shadowColor = color.copy(alpha = alpha).toArgb()
    val transparentColor = color.copy(alpha = 0f).toArgb()

    drawIntoCanvas {
        val paint = Paint()
        val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
        frameworkPaint.color = transparentColor
        frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
            shadowBlurRadius.toPx(),
            offsetX.toPx(),
            offsetY.toPx(),
            shadowColor
        )
        it.drawRoundRect(
            0f,
            0f,
            this.size.width,
            this.size.height,
            cornersRadius.toPx(),
            cornersRadius.toPx(),
            paint
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! could you update default `alpha` value to `1f`? I spend some time trying to understand why it doesn't work =)

Comment: `frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer` is not working for Android API < 28 if hardware acceleration is enabled

Comment: @sergpetrov try Hernand Azevedo answer with makeBlur instead it doesn't use setShadowLayer

Comment: I think you have to add `@RequiresApi(Q)` notation because `setShadowLayer` needs hardware acceleration that only supports API Level 28+ (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel#drawing-support)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the below implementation and it works fine for me.

Reference => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122#comment106

```
    /**
 * Applies a shadow to the current box.
 *
 * @param color The color of the shadow.
 *
 * @param blurRadius The larger this value, the bigger the blur, so the shadow
 * becomes bigger and lighter.
 * If set to `0`, the shadow's edge is sharp.
 *
 * @param spreadRadius Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow
 * bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to shrink.
 *
 * @param offset Offsets the shadow from the box.
 *
 * @param shape The shape of the box, which is applied to the shadow as well.
 *
 * @param clip Whether to clip the content to [shape].
 *
 * @param inset Whether the shadow should be inset to [shape]; otherwise, it is
 * a drop shadow.
 *
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException Any of the following conditions holds:
 * - [color] is [Color.Unspecified],
 * - [blurRadius] is [Dp.Unspecified] or negative,
 * - [spreadRadius] is [Dp.Unspecified],
 * - [offset] is [DpOffset.Unspecified].
 */
@Stable
fun Modifier.boxShadow(
    color: Color,
    blurRadius: Dp,
    spreadRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    offset: DpOffset = DpOffset.Zero,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    clip: Boolean = true,
    inset: Boolean = false
): Modifier {

    require(color.isSpecified) { "color must be specified." }
    require(blurRadius.isSpecified) { "blurRadius must be specified." }
    require(spreadRadius.isSpecified) { "spreadRadius must be specified." }
    require(blurRadius.value >= 0f) { "blurRadius can't be negative." }
    require(offset.isSpecified) { "offset must be specified." }

    return drawWithCache {
        onDrawWithContent {

            if (inset)
                drawContent()

            drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->

                val colorArgb = color.toArgb()
                val hasBlurRadius = blurRadius.value.let { it.isFinite() && it != 0f }
                val paint = Paint()

                paint.asFrameworkPaint().let { frameworkPaint ->

                    if (hasBlurRadius) {
                        frameworkPaint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(
                            blurRadius.toPx(),
                            BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL
                        )
                    }

                    frameworkPaint.color = colorArgb
                }

                val spreadRadiusPx = spreadRadius.toPx().let { spreadRadiusPx ->
                    when {
                        inset -> -spreadRadiusPx
                        else -> spreadRadiusPx
                    }
                }

                val hasSpreadRadius = spreadRadiusPx != 0f
                val size = size
                val layoutDirection = layoutDirection

                val density = Density(
                    density = density,
                    fontScale = fontScale
                )

                val shadowOutline = shape.createOutline(
                    size = when {
                        hasSpreadRadius -> size.let { (width, height) ->
                            (2 * spreadRadiusPx).let { outset ->
                                Size(
                                    width = width + outset,
                                    height = height + outset
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        else -> size
                    },
                    layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                    density = density
                )

                val nativeCanvas = canvas.nativeCanvas
                val count = nativeCanvas.save()

                if (inset) {

                    val boxOutline = when {
                        hasSpreadRadius -> shape.createOutline(
                            size = size,
                            layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                            density = density
                        )
                        else -> shadowOutline
                    }

                    canvas.clipToOutline(boxOutline)

                    val bounds = boxOutline.bounds

                    nativeCanvas.saveLayer(
                        bounds.left,
                        bounds.top,
                        bounds.right,
                        bounds.bottom,
                        NativePaint().apply {
                            colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                                ColorMatrix(
                                    floatArrayOf(
                                        1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 0f, 0f, -1f, 255f * color.alpha
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }

                canvas.translate(
                    dx = offset.x.toPx() - spreadRadiusPx,
                    dy = offset.y.toPx() - spreadRadiusPx
                )

                canvas.drawOutline(
                    outline = shadowOutline,
                    paint = paint
                )

                nativeCanvas.restoreToCount(count)
            }

            if (!inset)
                drawContent()
        }
    }.run {
        when {
            clip -> clip(shape)
            else -> this
        }
    }
}

fun Canvas.clipToOutline(
    outline: Outline,
    clipOp: ClipOp = ClipOp.Intersect
) {
    when (outline) {
        is Outline.Generic ->
            clipPath(path = outline.path, clipOp = clipOp)
        is Outline.Rectangle ->
            clipRect(rect = outline.rect, clipOp = clipOp)
        is Outline.Rounded ->
            clipPath(
                path = Path()
                    .apply { addRoundRect(outline.roundRect) },
                clipOp = clipOp
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Works with custom shaped! definitely the best answer I found for one side shadow to a custom shape after 2 days of working on this!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the post above, I've changed the implementation to match the parameters of the site below
https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/

My current implementation is the following

```
internal fun Modifier.coloredShadow(
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    borderRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    blurRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetY: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetX: Dp = 0.dp,
    spread: Float = 0f,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) = this.then(
    modifier.drawBehind {
        this.drawIntoCanvas {
            val paint = Paint()
            val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
            val spreadPixel = spread.dp.toPx()
            val leftPixel = (0f - spreadPixel) + offsetX.toPx()
            val topPixel = (0f - spreadPixel) + offsetY.toPx()
            val rightPixel = (this.size.width + spreadPixel)
            val bottomPixel =  (this.size.height + spreadPixel)

            if (blurRadius != 0.dp) {
                /*
                    The feature maskFilter used below to apply the blur effect only works
                    with hardware acceleration disabled.                   
                 */
                frameworkPaint.maskFilter =
                    (BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius.toPx(), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL))
            }

            frameworkPaint.color = color.toArgb()
            it.drawRoundRect(
                left = leftPixel,
                top = topPixel,
                right = rightPixel,
                bottom = bottomPixel,
                radiusX = borderRadius.toPx(),
                radiusY = borderRadius.toPx(),
                paint
            )
        }
    }
)
```

Feel free to add comments and help to evolve this gist
https://gist.github.com/hernandazevedo/dfd41b39d0156c740a195f6f5866ce20

Comment: Works well for JetBrains Compose, with the mask filter replaced with `MaskFilter.makeBlur(FilterBlurMode.NORMAL, blurRadius.toPx())`

Answer (score 2):

I've recently created shadow modifier allowing to set both radius and offsets.

```
@Immutable
data class Shadow(
    @Stable val offsetX: Dp,
    @Stable val offsetY: Dp,
    @Stable val radius: Dp,
    @Stable val color: Color,
)

fun Modifier.withShadow(
    shadow: Shadow,
    shape: Shape,
) = drawBehind {
    drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.asFrameworkPaint().apply {
            this.color = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            setShadowLayer(
                radius = shadow.radius.toPx(),
                dx = shadow.offsetX.toPx(),
                dy = shadow.offsetY.toPx(),
                shadowColor = shadow.color,
            )
        }
        val outline = shape.createOutline(size, layoutDirection, this)
        canvas.drawOutline(outline, paint)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is based on the above implementations, which implements all the features of the css box-shadow rule.

1. Ability to apply multiple shadows on the same box
2. Ability to set custom shape (example: RoundedCornerShape)
3. Adjustable (offset, blur, spread, color)
4. Support inner shadows

I hope it is useful for all of you

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawWithCache
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorMatrix
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Outline
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Paint
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawOutline
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.drawIntoCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.isSpecified
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.isSpecified

data class Shadow(
    val color: Color = Color.Black,
    val blurRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    val spreadRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    val offset: DpOffset = DpOffset.Zero,
    val inset: Boolean = false,
)

fun Modifier.boxShadow(
    vararg shadowList: Shadow,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    clip: Boolean = true,
): Modifier {
    return drawWithCache {
        onDrawWithContent {
            fun drawShadow(shadow: Shadow) {
                val color: Color = shadow.color;
                val blurRadius: Dp = shadow.blurRadius;
                val spreadRadius: Dp = shadow.spreadRadius;
                val offset: DpOffset = shadow.offset;
                val inset: Boolean = shadow.inset;

                require(color.isSpecified) { "color must be specified." }
                require(blurRadius.isSpecified) { "blurRadius must be specified." }
                require(blurRadius.value >= 0f) { "blurRadius can't be negative." }
                require(spreadRadius.isSpecified) { "spreadRadius must be specified." }
                require(offset.isSpecified) { "offset must be specified." }

                drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
                    val spreadRadiusPx = spreadRadius.toPx().let { spreadRadiusPx ->
                        when {
                            inset -> -spreadRadiusPx
                            else -> spreadRadiusPx
                        }
                    }

                    val hasSpreadRadius = spreadRadiusPx != 0f

                    val shadowOutline = shape.createOutline(size = when {
                        hasSpreadRadius -> size.let { (width, height) ->
                            (2 * spreadRadiusPx).let { outset ->
                                Size(
                                    width = width + outset, height = height + outset
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        else -> size
                    }, layoutDirection = layoutDirection, density = this)

                    canvas.save()

                    if (inset) {
                        val boxOutline = when {
                            hasSpreadRadius -> shape.createOutline(
                                size = size, layoutDirection = layoutDirection, density = this
                            )

                            else -> shadowOutline
                        }

                        canvas.clipToOutline(boxOutline)

                        canvas.saveLayer(boxOutline.bounds, Paint().apply {
                            colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(
                                ColorMatrix(
                                    floatArrayOf(
                                        1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
                                        0f, 0f, 0f, -1f, 255f * color.alpha
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        })
                    }

                    canvas.drawOutline(outline = shadowOutline, paint = Paint().also { paint ->
                        paint.asFrameworkPaint().apply {
                            this.color = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
                            setShadowLayer(
                                blurRadius.toPx(),
                                offset.x.toPx() - spreadRadiusPx,
                                offset.y.toPx() - spreadRadiusPx,
                                color.toArgb(),
                            )
                        }
                    })

                    if (inset) {
                        canvas.restore()
                    }

                    canvas.restore()
                }
            }

            for (shadow in shadowList.filter { !it.inset }) {
                drawShadow(shadow)
            }

            drawContent()

            for (shadow in shadowList.filter { it.inset }) {
                drawShadow(shadow)
            }
        }
    }.let { modifier -> if (clip) modifier.clip(shape) else modifier }
}

fun Canvas.clipToOutline(
    outline: Outline,
    clipOp: ClipOp = ClipOp.Intersect,
) {
    when (outline) {
        is Outline.Generic -> clipPath(path = outline.path, clipOp = clipOp)

        is Outline.Rectangle -> clipRect(rect = outline.rect, clipOp = clipOp)

        is Outline.Rounded -> clipPath(
            path = Path().apply { addRoundRect(outline.roundRect) }, clipOp = clipOp
        )
    }
}
```