# How can we fix the material shadow glitch on transparent/translucent Composables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

If you didn't know already, there's a defect with Android's material shadows, the ones that came with Material Design and its concepts of surfaces, lighting, and elevation. Also, if you didn't know, Compose utilizes many of the same graphics APIs as the `View` framework, including those responsible for said shadows, so it has the same glitch that `View`s do, at least for now.

[image: Screenshot of basic examples to compare and contrast.]

<sup>*`Card()`, `FloatingActionButton()`, `ExtendedFloatingActionButton()`, and `Surface()` shown with and without background translucency.*</sup>

For reasons I won't get into here,<sup>*</sup> I don't believe that there is any proper fix for this – i.e., I don't think that the platform offers any method or configuration by which to clip out or otherwise remove that artifact – so we're left with workarounds. Additionally, a main requirement is that the shadows appear exactly as the platform ones normally would, so any method that draws shadows with other techniques, like a uniform gradient or blur or whatnot, are not acceptable.

Given that, can we create a robust, generally applicable solution in Compose?

I personally landed on an overall approach of disabling the original shadow and drawing a clipped replica in its place. (I realize that simply punching a hole through it is not how shadows work realistically, but that seems to be the predominately expected effect.) I've shared an example of the Compose version of this in an answer below, but the primary motivation for this question was to check for better ideas before this is put into a library.

I'm sure that there are technical details in my example that can be improved, but I'm mainly curious about fundamentally different approaches or suggestions. I'm not interested in, for instance, somehow using `drawBehind()` or `Canvas()` instead to do essentially the same thing, or refactoring parameters just to slot the content in, etc. I'm thinking more along the lines of:

- Can you devise some other (more performant) way to trim that artifact without creating and clipping a separate shadow object? With `View`s, about the only way I found was to draw the `View` twice, with the content clipped in one draw and the shadow disabled in the other. I eventually decided against that, though, given the overhead.
- Can this be extracted to a `Modifier` and extension, similar to the `*GraphicsLayerModifier`s and `shadow()`/`graphicsLayer()`? I've not yet fully wrapped my head around all of Compose's concepts and capabilities, but I don't think so.
- Is there any other way to make this generally applicable, without requiring additional wiring? The shadow object in my example depends on three optional parameters with defaults from the target composable, and I can't think of any way to get at those, apart from wrapping the target with another composable.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> Those reasons are outlined in [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70227950).</sup>

**Clarifications**:

- It is necessary to preserve the `Composable`'s translucency/transparency, so we can still see what's behind it. Setting an opaque background color will not work here. The artifact needs to be fixed, not just covered over.

  If an opaque color would work for your particular setup – e.g, if the underlying content is a single solid color – you can simply use the `Color#compositeOver()` function to figure the opaque color that would result from your translucent one blending with the color behind it.
- This question is asking specifically about *material* shadows, the ones that are cast by `View`s/`RenderNode`s, and that cooperate with the on-screen draw routine and its two-source lighting model. `android.graphics.Paint`'s shadow layer is a separate mechanism that does not interact with that model, and therefore is not generating material shadows. It's just drawing a static, uniform gradient, which is noted above as being unacceptable here because it looks completely different than the material shadows.

  If `Paint`'s shadow layer would be suitable for your particular setup, there are many examples already available on-site, like those on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996525). There's no need to repeat them here.

Answer (score 12):

We're going to use `FloatingActionButton()` for this local example, since it supports about every option we need to consider, but this should be workable with any Composable. For convenience, I've wrapped several more common ones with this solution and assembled them in [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/zed-alpha/3dc931720292c1f3ff31fa6a130f52cd), if you'd want to try something other than just `FloatingActionButton()`.

We want our wrapper Composable to act as a drop-in replacement, so its parameter list and default values are copied exactly from `FloatingActionButton()`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClippedShadowFloatingActionButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(CornerSize(percent = 50)),
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: FloatingActionButtonElevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        {
            ClippedShadow(
                elevation = elevation.elevation(interactionSource).value,
                shape = shape,
                modifier = modifier
            )
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = onClick,
                modifier = modifier,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                shape = shape,
                backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
                contentColor = contentColor,
                elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),
                content = content
            )
        },
        modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        require(measurables.size == 2)

        val shadow = measurables[0]
        val target = measurables[1]

        val targetPlaceable = target.measure(constraints)
        val width = targetPlaceable.width
        val height = targetPlaceable.height

        val shadowPlaceable = shadow.measure(Constraints.fixed(width, height))

        layout(width, height) {
            shadowPlaceable.place(0, 0)
            targetPlaceable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

We're basically wrapping a `FloatingActionButton()` and our replica shadow Composable in a `Layout()` optimized for the setup. Most of the parameters are passed untouched to the wrapped `FloatingActionButton()` except for the `elevation`, which we zero out to disable the inherent shadow. Instead, we direct to our `ClippedShadow()` the appropriate raw elevation value, which is calculated here using the `FloatingActionButtonElevation` and `InteractionSource` parameters. Simpler Composables like `Card()` will have stateless elevation values in `Dp` that can be passed straight through.

`ClippedShadow()` itself is another custom `Layout()`, but with no content:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClippedShadow(elevation: Dp, shape: Shape, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Layout(
        modifier
            .drawWithCache {
                // Naive cache setup similar to foundation's Background.
                val path = Path()
                var lastSize: Size? = null

                fun updatePathIfNeeded() {
                    if (size != lastSize) {
                        path.reset()
                        path.addOutline(
                            shape.createOutline(size, layoutDirection, this)
                        )
                        lastSize = size
                    }
                }

                onDrawWithContent {
                    updatePathIfNeeded()
                    clipPath(path, ClipOp.Difference) {
                        this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
                    }
                }
            }
            .shadow(elevation, shape)
    ) { _, constraints ->
        layout(constraints.minWidth, constraints.minHeight) {}
    }
}
```

We need it only for its shadow and `Canvas` access, which we get with two simple `Modifier` extensions. `drawWithCache()` lets us keep a simple `Path` cache we use to clip and restore around the entire content draw, and `shadow()` is rather self-explanatory. With this Composable layered behind the target, whose own shadow is disabled, we get the desired effect:

[image: Screenshot of the question's examples fixed.]

As in the question, the first three are `Card()`, `FloatingActionButton()`, and `ExtendedFloatingActionButton()`, but wrapped in our fix. To demonstrate that the `InteractionSource`/elevation redirect works as intended, [this brief gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48QVo.gif) shows two `FloatingActionButton()`s with fully transparent backgrounds side by side; the one on the right has our fix applied.

For the fourth example in the image of fixes above, we used a solo `ClippedShadow()`, simply to illustrate that it works on its own, as well:

```kotlin
ClippedShadow(
    elevation = 10.dp,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
    modifier = Modifier.size(FabSize)
)
```

Just like the regular composables, it should work with any `Shape` that's valid for the current API level. Arbitrary convex `Path`s work on all relevant versions, and starting with API level 29 (Q), concave ones do, too.

[image: Screenshot of ClippedShadow() with various Shapes made from irregular Paths.]

Comment: I've an alternate solution available in the form of a `Modifier` and extension function in [my library on GitHub](https://github.com/zed-alpha/shadow-gadgets). Since it's used just like `shadow()`, I don't think an explanation or example is really necessary here, so I'll just leave it linked in this comment for now.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem in my case when I use it on compose desktop

Comment: @Roony Yeah, sorry, this whole post is really only meant to be for Android. I guess it's not very obvious unless you look at the tags on the question, but Stack Overflow doesn't want us to put tag names in the title. I haven't had a chance to play with Compose desktop yet, so I can't give any suggestions at the moment, but I'll let ya know if I learn anything useful in the near future. Cheers!

Comment: Actually I know that it's not about compose desktop, but I thought it would work regardless because both are compose.

Answer (score 0):

Compose for Desktop has the same problem. I haven't tried it on Android yet, but on Desktop, if a shape has a path consisting of two conturs (it could also be a pierced shape variant like a donut), then its shadow will be solid. Therefore, for the case of a custom shape, you can use a workaround and draw a small dot in the distance. If the dot is less than a pixel it won't work, but it could very well be off screen.

```
class CustomShapeForShadow(private val path: Path) : Shape {
  override fun createOutline(
    size: Size,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    density: Density
  ): Outline {
    val p2 = Path().apply {
        addRect(Rect(Offset(-100000f, -100000f), Size(10f, 10f)))
    }
    val pathRez = Path()
    pathRez.op(path, p2, PathOperation.Union)
    return Outline.Generic(path = pathRez)
  }
}
```

This solution does not look good. But at least in the first approximation, it works.
Perhaps it is necessary to be more careful with the remoteness of this dot. If you use the resulting shape only for the shadow or surface, it seems that there are no performance problems. But if this shape is also use for the background and borders, the load is clearly visible at greater distances. That is why it is better to use a separate shape for background and borders.
The result is not like in the example above, but it no longer looks like a defect.

Answer (score -2):

Just set background parameter:

`backgroundColor = colors.background`

Example for `PullRefreshIndicator`:

```
PullRefreshIndicator(
    refreshing = refreshing,
    state = pullRefreshState,
    modifier = Modifier.align(
        Alignment.TopCenter
    ),
    backgroundColor = colors.background
)
```