# Android Compose Shadow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, shadow

Is Android Jetpack Compose shadow modifier supposed to look like this?

[image: Screenshot of Text with a shadow modifier]

I'm so confused. I've written a few components and I'm testing the shadow modifier that I believe was introduced in compose-1.2.0-alpha. I'm now using 1.2.1. My component is written as this.

```
fun Labels() {
    Label(
        modifier = Modifier.shadow(
            elevation = 1.dp, 
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp), 
            ambientColor = Color.Blue, 
            spotColor = Color.Blue
        ), 
        text = field.name, 
        style = typographies.tagDefault
    )
}
```

Label is a mirror copy of Text for my own reasons, but that means it boils down to::

```
fun Label(...) {
    BasicText(
        text,
        modifier,
        mergedStyle,
        onTextLayout,
        overflow,
        softWrap,
        maxLines,
    )
}
```

So in the grand scheme and to my understanding the shadow effect is ultimately being applied to the `BasicText` and nothing else. Which looks like the case in the image, but why is it so thick? Why isn't it more like a border the same as `box-shadow` in CSS? How can I make it look like it should with similarities to `box-shadow` in CSS? I've tried a few things like moving the modifier to higher component pieces and messing with the elevation. But all that has done is made the shadow a little hazy and maybe slightly thicker. Also if I change the shape to something like `RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50)` it nearly fills in the whole background with this blue color which is definitely not intended.

Comment: That's Android's material shadow artifact, which you're seeing because the background is transparent. It's been around since Lollipop. The simplest way to get rid of it is to use opaque backgrounds; e.g., by setting your `Label`'s background to a solid white. If you really need transparent backgrounds, just without that artifact, it'll take some sort of workaround, AFAIK.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm assuming you don't know the workaround right now?? Or if you do it is more complicated then it is worth maybe? I am about 89% sure I need transparent backgrounds for the purposes of my future work. But I thought about that being the issue for sure. :(

Comment: Here ya go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71868520. Most users end up not really needing it, so I only link it if asked.

Comment: oof that's rough. thank you.