# Shadow is being cut off

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm trying to apply elevation to an item, but the shadow is being cut off from the top and start, it's only applied fully to the end.

code:

```
  Surface(
        elevation = 12.dp,
        color = LocalColors.current.Ivory,
         shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(vertical = 20.dp, horizontal = 24.dp),
        ) {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            ) {
                content()
            }
            Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
            PrimaryButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (isRemoveEnabled) {
                        onClickRemove()
                    } else {
                        onClickReleases()
                    }
                },
                backgroundColor = if (isRemoveEnabled) Color(0xFFFAEEF0) else Color(0xFF418DCB),
                border = BorderStroke(
                    width = if (isRemoveEnabled) 1.dp else 0.dp,
                    color = if (isRemoveEnabled) Color(0xFFE39393) else Color.Transparent
                ),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = if (isRemoveEnabled) "Remove" else "Release",
                    style = LocalTextStyle.current.labelMedium,
                    color = if (isRemoveEnabled) Color(0xFFCC2B49) else Color.White,
                )
            }
           
            // more content
        }
    }
```

I've different ways to fix it, I tried to use the item without putting it in a lazy column but it appears the same way.

this is a screenshot:

[image]

any help?

edit:

I forgot to mention that this is happening on compose desktop.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or image of how you would like things to appear?

Comment: @tomerpacific I just want even shadow on all sides, just to show it elevated on the background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a default behavior for shadow in Compose Desktop. The shadow is offsetted from top-left to bottom-right corner.

On my side, I tried to set elevation directly to Surface and via modifier

```
.shadow(elevation = 10.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
```

The result is the same as yours. Also the shadow might be cut-off at the bottom in your case, cause there is no enough space for shadow there. Try to play around with a padding.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that the behavior changes when you have a smaller layout. There is a solution to this problem but it doesn't work on compose desktop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868521/15514510 It makes the shadow kind of better on desktop when decreasing the value of targetPlaceable width and height, but you have to know which specific value works relative to the size of your layout.

Answer (score -1):

You should add elevation into your item layout. For this, use shadow function

```
   Row(

    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
        .height(56.dp)
        .shadow(
            elevation = 4.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        )
) { /* your code */ }
```