# How to make gradient text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to add gradient fill to my `Text` composable like below. Please help.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203208/text-gradient-in-android-jetpack-compose this might help you